# tire sizes do not match correctly

Tags: tire

I have a tire size of `40-622` and `700X38`:
[image]

But when I look at the [table](http://biketiresize.com/) I see that it does not match:

```
40-622  28 x 1-5/8 x 1-3/4  700 x 40C   28 x 1½ x 1,75  1995    Find tires
38-622  28 x 1-5/8 x 1½     700 x 38C   28 x 1½ x 1,75  1995    Find tires
```

You see how on the first line we got `40-622` (in the first column) and in the second line we got `700 x 38C` (in the third column)? So what's the actual size of my tire?

Comment: With regard to the 38 v 40, I've seen that on other tires and I assume they're using a different reference rim width which therefore yields a different width for the mounted tire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tire sizing is a mess. [Read it and weep](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html).

"700" or more properly "700C" is derived from an old French tire-sizing system; the number indicates the outside diameter of the tire in that system (700 mm), and the "C" indicates the width of a tire under that system (meaning "wide,"). "622" represents the *bead seat diameter* (or, approximately, the inside diameter of the tire) of a 700C tire, under the modern ETRTO sizing system. These days we use "700C" as the name for a size with a tenuous relationship to its original measurements (curiously, 700C has mostly survived as the name of the size for skinny road tires); "622" is more precise.

You'll see that these tires are *also* called 28" on that table, which is extra-fun because they're slightly *smaller* than 27" tires (which have become very uncommon), but have exactly the same bead-seat diameter as tires labeled 29" (used on mountain bikes).

Why the widths (38/40) aren't the same is less clear to me. Maybe the company has their own system for measuring widths that is slightly different from the ETRTO system.

Comment: what am I suppose to do? What to buy? My tread is worn off.

Comment: Any tire that is labelled as 700C or ETRTO 622 (or both, as in this case), and that has approximately the same width, will fit.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between 38 and 40 is 2mm, so there's probably more size variation than that between different brands.   Either is fine, depends which one you can find to buy locally.

In theory wider tyres are squashier, for more comfortable ride, as long as they fit inside your frame.

The slightly smaller tyres would be slightly faster, and being smaller would definitely fit in the frame.